# How to put checkout revision number of a build in ftl email template of atlassian bamboo

Tags: freemarker, bamboo

I want to put the revision number (current checkout revision which is used to build) in ftl email templates of atlassian bamboo specifically in `notificationCommonsHTML.ftl` in templateOuter macro before the line "was successful" or "failed". (line 15)

FYI: I use the SVN repo and corresponding revision number for the build

I tried `${buildSummary.revision}` but had no luck. Please help me with this; the documentation for modifying email templates is abysmal.